# How to test Facebook API actions locally?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm building a facebook app and so far so good but when I want to add an action (i.e. an article etc.) which would point to an outside url like "**example.com/articles/12**" it doesn't work since I'm developing using local urls like "**localhost/dev/myprogram/articles/12**" and Facebook obviously cannot fetch it.

What's a good way to solve this? Mind that the application doesn't exist on a live domain yet either, so I can't use that space.

I set up the app for the development with my localhost domain and since Facebook uses an iframe it works perfectly, but once I want to actually save objects it fails because of this problem.

so lets say I have an url like:

```
http://localhost/dev/myprogram/articles/12
```

then facebook first tries to parse it via

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://localhost/dev/myprogram/articles/12&scrape=true
```

and then save the new object with something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/myprogram:upload?article=http://localhost/dev/myprogram/articles/12
```

This will fail because even though Facebook can reach my localhost trough the iframe, it cant reach this page from anywhere else.

Any workarounds for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What's a good way to solve this?

Either get some publicly reachable space to test your stuff on (could be a subdomain of your actual project domain, for example) – or set up your local development machine to be reachable from the interwebs, by using a DynDNS service of some sort.